# How to Translate a text online Using Firebase ML kit without Downloading its Model?

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to translate a text to a target language using firebase ML kit but it only translates in between languages whose model is downloaded. I wants to translate even if model is not downloaded

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                TranslatorOptions options = new TranslatorOptions.Builder()
                        .setSourceLanguage(languageCodes[sourcode])
                        .setTargetLanguage(languageCodes[destcode])
                        .build();
                final Translator translator = Translation.getClient(options);
                getLifecycle().addObserver(translator);
                translator.translate(params[0])
                        .addOnSuccessListener(s -> TranslationFragment.this.requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> translationBinding.translatedText.setText(s))).addOnFailureListener(e -> TranslationFragment.this.requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Translation Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()));
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                isTranslationsupported = false;

            } finally {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: It does not provide a API  i guess . https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit . whole idea of using a model is to have on device capabilities .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ML Kit's Translation API is meant for doing translation on-device and it needs to download language packs to make that work. If you want to do translation using a cloud API, please check out [Google Cloud Translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate).